# How to create a responsive bottom border for titles in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm looking to replicate the following design in CSS:

[image]

So far I've done the following:

```css
.bb-title::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7D18FD;
  width: 25%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='f2 mt4 bb-title relative'>
  What people are saying
</h2>
```

But this isn't responsive.

See the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/MWYmGOo).

What is the best way to achieve a bottom border on titles, where the border will always be the same width as the title?

Comment: make h2 display:inline-block or display:table then you can use width:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this and remove the old styling

```
.bb-titlee{
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7D18FD;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

h2 elements are displayed as blocks as default, if we set it to inline it will wrap around the text and contain that width.

Comment: I'll accept this answer when the time allows, thank you

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

follow these steps:

```
.bb-title {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bb-title::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #7D18FD;
   width: 100%;
   height: 3px;
   bottom: -5px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the element inline and then add a bottom border to it like the code bellow:

```
.bb-title{
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7D18FD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.bb-title
{
  display:inline;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #7D18FD;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html :

```html
<div class='d-flex fl'>
  <h2 class='f2 mt4 header'>What people are saying</h2>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```css
.header{
  margin:0 !important
}
.line{
  flex: 1;
  border:1px solid #7D18FD;
}
```